# inverse fft producing close but wrong output

Tags: c++, math, fft

I'm performing a radix-2 dif inverse fft.  I'm using the properties of conjugation and scaling to return the result. I conjugate my input vector, perform a regular radix-2 fft(not ifft), conjugate the results, then scale by 1.0/N.  However, I'm not getting the correct results:

```
int main(){ 
    const int n = 4;
    complex<double> x[n];

        // Test signal

    x[0] = complex<double>(10,0);
    x[1] = complex<double>(-2,0);
    x[2] = complex<double>(-2,2);
    x[3] = complex<double>(-2,-2);

        print(x,n);

    fft_inverse(x,n); 

    print(x,n); 

}
//dif fft. works
void fft(complex<double> X[], int N){
        if(N == 1){return;} 

    complex<double> *temp = new complex<double>[N]; 
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        temp[i]=X[i];
        }   
        for(int i = 0; i<N/2; i++){
        complex<double> tw(cos(-2*M_PI*i/N),sin(-2*M_PI*i/N)); 
            X[i] = temp[i] + temp[i+N/2];
            X[i+N/2] = temp[i]-temp[i+N/2];
            X[i+N/2] = X[i+N/2]*tw;   
        }

        fft(X,N/2);
        fft(X+N/2,N/2);
}
void fft_inverse(complex<double> X[], int N){
    //conjugate
    for(int i = 0; i<N;i++){
        X[i] = conj(X[i]);
    }
    //perform fft
    fft(X,N);
    //conjugate again
    for(int i = 0; i<N;i++){
        X[i] = conj(X[i]);
    }
    //scale by 1.0/N
    double norm_N = 1.0/N;
    for(int i = 0; i<N;i++){
        X[i] *= norm_N;
    }
}
```

Here are my results:
Input:

> (10,0)
>       (-2,0)
>       (-2,2)
>       (-2,-2)

Output:

> (1,-0)
>       (3,1)
>       (2.5,-0.5)
>       (3.5,-0.5)

The output should be:

> (1,0)
>       (2,0)
>       (3,0)
>       (4,0)

What's going on?  I've tested my `fft` on what the output should be and received the correct result, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is giving the correct output but the bins are in the wrong order:

```
octave> X = [ 10, -2, -2+2i, -2-2i ] 
X =

   10 +  0i   -2 +  0i   -2 +  2i   -2 -  2i

octave> x = ifft(X)
x =

   1.00000 + 0.00000i   2.50000 - 0.50000i   3.00000 + 1.00000i   3.50000 - 0.50000i
```

`fft_inverse()` looks OK so I suspect `fft()` could use some further testing/debugging - it may be that you need to do some bit reversal for your indexing.

Comment: I agree that `fft` is probably the culprit. If the time domain signal was indeed `1, 2, 3, 4` which is real, then the FFT of that should have been symmetric. Which it is not.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, however, I've tested `fft` on the input `(1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0)` and received the correct result..

Comment: Try a different and/or longer FFT - compare the results with a known good FFT, e.g. MATLAB/Octave/Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Well, we are both right. The FFT for a real function is symmetric, and so is your result :)  It's just that it is shifted, and difficult to see when you only have four values.

Answer (score 1):

Let's review the basics: The inverse fft of length 2N evaluates a polynomial `p(z)` of degree 2N at roots of unity `q^i` where `q^N = -1`. To do that fast, the polynomial is split into even and odd parts, `p(z)=pe(z^2)+z*po(z^2)`. Then

```
p(q^i)    =pe(q^2i)+q^i*po(q^2i)
p(q^(N+i))=pe(q^2i)-q^i*po(q^2i)
```

In the implementations, the values of pe and po are obtained by recursive calls to `ifft` of length N.

The forward fft is now the inverse operation of that, computing coefficients of a polynomial from its values. To do that, the values of `p(q^i)` are transformed into values of `pe(q^2i)` and `po(q^2i)` by reversing the above formulas,

```
pe(q^2i)=0.5*(p(q^i)+p(q^(N+i)))
po(q^2i)=0.5*(p(q^i)-p(q^(N+i)))*q^(-i)
```

which you should recognize from your code. Then fft is recursively called to determine the coefficients of pe and po from their now computed values. The factors 0.5 are usually omitted and applied collected as a division by the array length outside of the fft routines.

Where you went wrong now is in the fact that the coefficients of pe and po appear alternating, interleaved, in the coefficient sequence of p. The famous butterfly pattern.

```
void fft(complex<double> X[], int N){
    fft_internal(X,N,1);
}

void fft_internal(complex<double> X[], int N, int step){
    if(N == 1){return;} 

    complex<double> *temp = new complex<double>[N]; 
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        temp[i]=X[step*i];
    }   
    for(int i = 0; i<N/2; i++){
    complex<double> tw(cos(-2*M_PI*i/N),sin(-2*M_PI*i/N)); 
        X[2*step*i     ] =  temp[i] + temp[i+N/2];
        X[2*step*i+step] = (temp[i] - temp[i+N/2])*tw;   
    }

    fft_internal(X     ,N/2, 2*step);
    fft_internal(X+step,N/2, 2*step);
}
```

With the correctly reordered inputs ([2]<-->[1]),

```
// Test signal

x[0] = complex<double>(10,0);
x[1] = complex<double>(-2,2);
x[2] = complex<double>(-2,0);
x[3] = complex<double>(-2,-2);
```

this returns the expected result.